# vim change text on multiple lines with different text placement?

Tags: vim, replace

How you change the text inside the closing tag on multiple lines ??
The opening one is simple - I make a visual block with c-v and change it how to do this from the end of line ??

```
        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Email me</a></li>
```

Comment: you make a visual block with c-i? what?

Comment: ctrl + v - was thinking about writing the text later using shift + I ;)
Changed

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. Can you post what the end result could look like?

Answer (score 0):

As a text editor (that doesn't have a particular strong model of the text structure except for syntax highlighting, and that information is hardly used for editing tasks), Vim doesn't offer an elegant and easy solution for this. However, there are multiple possible approaches:

#### substitution

Unless you have some mappings to set this up, it's a lot to type, but very generic:

```
:1,3substitute#</li>$#</div>#
```

#### a trick

As you specificially asked about visual block mode, you can temporarily right-align the text to do this:

```
:1,3right
" Use <C-v> to select the (now aligned) tags, and edit them.
:1,3left    " Or re-indent via 3==
```

#### with plugin help

[vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors.git) is one of the most prominent implementations of the idea of having multiple edit locations within the current buffer that apply edits in parallel to each one. With its mappings, you can select all end tags, and then edit them all together (e.g. via `cdiv<Esc>`).

Comment: Thank you for all the tricks. I will have a look at the multiple cursors plugin as well. I feel that it will come in handy in the future.